# Why is my exponential decay not working?

Tags: python, math, simulation, exponential

I'm simulating exponential decay. Why is it not working? Here's the code

```
from math import *
from random import random
from time import sleep

class atom():
    def __init__(self, pos):
        self.pos = pos
        self.isalive = True

class substance():
    def __init__(self, halflife):
        self.halflife = float(halflife)
        self.rate = float(log(2) / self.halflife)
        self.life = float(0)
        self.probdecay = float(0)
        self.struct = [atom(i) for i in range(100)]
        self.isalive = True
        print self.rate

    def sim(self):
        print self.probdecay
        for i in range(len(self.struct)):
            if self.struct[i].isalive:
                if random() < self.probdecay:
                    self.struct[i].isalive = False

        self.life += 1.0
        self.probdecay = 1.0 - pow(1.0 - self.rate, self.life)

    def getstr(self):
        s = ""
        for i in self.struct:
            if i.isalive:
                s += "o"
            else:
                s += " "
        return s

s = substance(5)

while s.isalive:
    s.sim()
    print s.getstr()
    sleep(1)
```

Here's the output

```
0.138629436112
0.0
oooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo
0.138629436112
oooooo o ooooooooooo oooooooo ooooooo o oooooooooooo oooooo oooooooo oooo ooo oooooooo  oooo   oooo 
0.258040751667
o  ooo o   oo oo ooo o    ooo o ooooo o oo  oooooo o   oooo  oo oooo oo   ooo ooo  ooo   ooo   oo   
0.360898143882
   o o     oo     oo o    ooo   ooo o   oo  o o oo     o o    o    o o    ooo o o   oo   o o   oo   
0.449496473814
   o        o        o    o o    o      o     o        o      o      o     o                   oo   
0.525812467226
   o        o                    o      o     o                      o                              
0.591548817506
            o                           o                                                           
0.648172174615

0.696945867656

0.738958091134

0.775146183762
```

Obviously, that is not exponential decay with  halflife of 5. What's going on here?

Comment: Why does the decay probability change over time?

Comment: Exponential probability distribution is [memory-less](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memorylessness) so the probability of decay shouldn't change. A style note: in the `sim` method why do you iterate over the indices? Do `for atom in self.struct: if atom.isalive and random() < self.probdecay: atom.isalive = False`.

Comment: @Bakuriu I generally find it food practice to iterate over indecies in case I ever need to use the index for something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you mixed up the probability of a particle decaying *on* a certain step, and the probability of a particle decaying *by* a given step. The probability of a particle decaying *on* any given step is the same, regardless of which step it is, while the probability that a particle has decayed *by* a given step is monotonically increasing. Instead of gradually increasing `probdecay`, set it once, when you initialize the `substance`:

```
def __init__(self, halflife):
    self.probdecay = 1 - 0.5 ** (1.0 / halflife)
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks bro. I'm not chemist or anything so I don't know this stuff ;)